# vim-abolish Echos Extra matches inside of vim

Tags: vim

I use Vim and Gvim and many of the plugins that this text editor supports.  I would like to use the vim-abolish plugin and yet find that it does not work correctly.  Specifically, if I execute the following command:

```
:Abolish {despa,sepe}rat{e,es,ed,ing,ely,ion,ions,or}  {despe,sepa}rat{}
```

from the vim-abolish documentation, the expected behavior is not evident when I type a word like "desparate" in the vim window.  Instead, I see output like this:

```
* desperate
i  desparates  * desperates
i  desparated  * desperated
```

That is, vim makes the correct substitution and then it also gives me additional debugging information about the other substitutions that are available.  Just like I have seem in previous VimCasts, I would like to only see the substitution and not the extra information.

I have tried to comment out a wide variety of lines in my .vimrc file in order to determine if they might be causing this type of behavior. So far, all of the various configuration commands that I have commented out all lead to the same behavior.  Thus far, I have not yet tried to comment out the various plugins that I am loading from vundle, as listed below:

```
    Bundle 'gmarik/vundle'
    " Add any bundles that you want to install to this location
    Bundle 'https://github.com/yuratomo/gmail.vim.git'
    Bundle 'https://github.com/altercation/vim-colors-solarized.git'
    Bundle 'https://github.com/vim-scripts/Xoria256m.git'
    Bundle 'https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree.git'
    Bundle 'https://github.com/vim-scripts/dbext.vim.git'
    Bundle 'https://github.com/kien/ctrlp.vim.git'
    Bundle 'https://github.com/xolox/vim-misc.git'
    Bundle 'https://github.com/xolox/vim-session.git'
    Bundle 'https://github.com/majutsushi/tagbar'
    Bundle 'https://github.com/gerw/vim-latex-suite.git'
    Bundle 'https://github.com/gregsexton/gitv.git'
    Bundle 'https://github.com/bling/vim-airline.git'
    Bundle 'https://github.com/vim-scripts/HTML-AutoCloseTag.git'
    Bundle 'https://github.com/tpope/vim-abolish.git'
    Bundle 'https://github.com/terryma/vim-multiple-cursors.git'
    Bundle 'https://github.com/justinmk/vim-sneak.git'
    Bundle 'https://github.com/joeytwiddle/sexy_scroller.vim.git'
    Bundle 'https://github.com/kablamo/vim-git-log.git'
    Bundle 'https://github.com/vim-scripts/TeX-9.git'
    Bundle 'https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic.git'
    Bundle 'https://github.com/Valloric/MatchTagAlways.git'
    Bundle 'https://github.com/ervandew/supertab.git'
    Bundle 'https://github.com/xolox/vim-easytags.git'
    Bundle 'https://github.com/MarcWeber/vim-addon-mw-utils'
    Bundle 'https://github.com/tomtom/tlib_vim'
    Bundle 'https://github.com/garbas/vim-snipmate'
    Bundle 'https://github.com/onza/vim-snippets'
    Bundle 'https://github.com/vim-scripts/Marks-Browser.git'
    Bundle 'https://github.com/vim-scripts/AutoTag.git'
    Bundle 'https://github.com/int3/vim-extradite.git'
    Bundle 'https://github.com/Keithbsmiley/investigate.vim.git'
```

I also have tried to run iabbrev commands without using vim-abolish and this does not produce the aforementioned behavior. That is, the word is replaced with the correct spelling without seeing any extra debugging information.

Finally, I did not see any points related to this matter on the vim-abolish issues tracker and I could not find any previous postings on stack overflow about the matter.

So, before I start going through my .vimrc file line by line and trying different combinations of vim plugins, I was hoping that someone could spot the problem.  Any ideas? Thanks for any assistance that you can provide!

Comment: Well no. Going through your config line by line is precisely what you should do before askong random strangers.

Comment: Works for me as expected. Which Vim, plugin version? Also, do you see this with just the Abolish plugin active?

Comment: You should probably try commenting out *all* your plugins, and see if it works ok then.  If it does, then [bisectly](https://github.com/dahu/bisectly) might help you track down which plugin(s) conflict with Abolish.